# What does this mean in datasheet : 2k: Ipgm/10 for term; Ipgm/5 for precharge

Tags: battery-charging, datasheet, lipo, texas-instruments, bms

I was referencing the datasheet for BQ24040 Texas Instrument IC and could not understand the following statement and what does it actually mean. I am new to this. Can some one explain what does it mean.

[image]

This is on page '4' in the datasheet. Reference datasheet can be found here: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq24040.pdf

Comment: Ipgm is the programmed current, I believe.

Comment: I was wondering if 'Ipgm' is equal to fast charge current ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When charging, the charging is terminated when charging current has dropped to I/10, i.e. the battery is full.

When battery is really low on charge, it is slowly charged at I/5 before it is safe to charge it with full current.

These are achieved with 2k resistor.

Comment: Is the 'I' in 'I/5' the Ipgm ? Is 'Ipgm' the fast charge current ?

Comment: search for the word `fast` in the document

Answer (score 0):

*Expected range of programming resistor is 1k to 10kΩ (2k: Ipgm/10 for term; Ipgm/5 for precharge)*

**Iset** = CC then CV then cutoff= Fast Charge mode  =Ipgm
Ipre = 2*Iterm.
term.=cutoff
2 kΩ = 10% cutoff = 20% precharge

Some use 5% for slightly **more capacity** yet more **ageing**.

This is a user **tradeoff** choice, as is Depth of discharge >50%.